# Visual Studio not applying colors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, color-scheme

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with F# Power Tools for programming F#.

I changed the colors for a few things, but my F#-files (fsx and fs) are still looking like they looked before.
[image]

Source:

[image]

I googled for a while, but cannot find any solution.
Since F# is missing parentheses, it would be really helpful to highlight function names and types.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but disabling and enabling the F# Power Tools fixed it.